# Get transaction detail from transaction hash in Tezos api

Tags: transactions, hash

I am trying to retrieve transaction detail using transaction hash to get transaction status.

I searched tezos apis, but I can't find available one.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [TzKt's API](https://api.tzkt.io/) for this.

[Transaction by Hash](https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Operations_GetTransactionByHash) will get the transaction details, and
[Operation by Hash](https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Operations_GetByHash) will get you any kind of operation details on Tezos.

Examples:

https://api.tzkt.io/v1/operations/oopbywKbkCt4atGuc7yT7jgxwXoSBRTLdo77BtycKrEwXvst7vP
https://api.tzkt.io/v1/operations/transactions/opYg8QerKizm49vSnsrWk6biBpcR4QqUba87kKgp7ZZSv7TvKQ6