# Get transaction details from operation hash with taquito

Tags: tezos-client, taquito, tzkt, operation-hash

How fetch details about my transaction from operation hash. I am using taquito library. I searched and get that tzkt can be used but can tzkt taquito extension be used. If yes then how.

Comment: If you only have the operationHash and no other details, i'd recommend using TzKT directly for this. See this previous question/answer: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/4550/4665

Answer (score 1):

In taquito to get operation object from operation hash is through crawling each block, how to is showed below. If you’re looking for indexer way, currently there is no implementation of “tzkt taquito extension”. Might need to check their api doc and make http requests separately from taquito

In taquito:
You can use `await Tezos.operation.createOperation(‘opHash’)`
this method by default will be looking from head block and onward.

If you’re looking for past operations and know this operation is at least at what block and onward you can pass the second param to specify which block to look onward `await Tezos.operation.createOperation(‘opHash’, { blockIdentifier: ‘blockNo’ });`

The downsides of using `createOperation` is, it might take long until the crawling is completed, user might need to know where approximately the operation is and the crawling will be limited by which history mode the rpc node’s is running if that preserve complete operation history.

Answer (score 0):

You can use taquito to get the operation details directly from the Tezos node:

```
import { TezosToolkit } from "@taquito/taquito";

async function main() {
    const Tezos = new TezosToolkit('https://ghostnet.ecadinfra.com');
    const operation = await Tezos.operation.createOperation('op4B3byB2A3R8HTCDGwuJVPsJA546RUpQcv2bhjtQ1CzZzzNJng');
    console.log(operation);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```